# Codignator library require not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and I am trying to load a library. The below code is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
require(APPPATH'.libraries/REST_Controller.php');
```

Comment: This makes no sense. What are you even trying to do? Thats not how you load controllers, nor libraries.

Comment: REST API with codeignator

Comment: your question lacks info. what is not working? where are you using that in your library?controller?model? others?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because `E_NOT_WORKING` is not a proper error state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, even i use REST Controller and what you have used is perfect that i can vouch for. So the problem is not in that particular line.

I use :

> require(APPPATH'.libraries/REST_Controller.php');

in my controller make sure you extend REST_Controller like this :

> require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');
>
> class My_class extends REST_Controller {
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

To load a library in CodeIgniter, you use the built in `load` functions.

E.g.

```
$this->load->library('library');
```